# Can't play stunt rally

Tags: games

everytime I try to start stunt rally via the command prompt I get following error..

```
./stuntrally: error while loading shared libraries: libOgreMain.so.1.7.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

any ideas???

I am running Natty 32bit

Comment: Please can you add to your question, the version of ubuntu and whether you are running 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default download of the game from [PlayDeb](http://www.playdeb.net/software/StuntRally) has an error.  I have contacted the PlayDeb team - they have turned around a new compilation (fantastic - well done the PlayDeb team).

If you do an update via Update Manager, it should find the new version for you to install.  Have fun!

Comment: that is the thing, I did download it from playdeb....